# Content Syndication for Twitter and Facebook Post

Tags: marketing-cloud

I was wondering if it is possible if I can render/publish Tweets or Facebook post or Facebook Comments in Email? So something like dynamic content syndication in real time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adam's correct, however the issue with using the AMPscript `HTTPGet()` function is that that most APIs these days require some flavor of OAuth credentials to be present in the HTTP request header and `HTTPGet()` doesn't support that.

My suggestion would be to look at using the [SSJS](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/server_side_javascript/) `HTTP.Get()` function to make the API request and then format the JSON payload response using [GTL](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/guide_template_language/).

I've put together a simple example below, which uses Twitter's [user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) API method to retrieve the lastest five tweets from my Twitter feed.

*You are welcome to replicate the example below, but you will need to create your own [Twitter App](https://apps.twitter.com) first to obtain your own consumer keys and access tokens.*

```js
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <head>
        <script runat="server">

        Platform.Load("Core","1");

        var url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=eliotharper&count=5";
        var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
        var headerValues = ["OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",oauth_token=\"1234567-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1471761254\",oauth_nonce=\"uTpJPz\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\""];
        var response = HTTP.Get(url, headerNames, headerValues);
        Variable.SetValue("twitterFeed",response.Content);

        </script>
     </head>
  <body>
     <h2>Feed</h2>
     <ul>
     {{.datasource feed type=variable}}
        {{.data}}
           { "target" : "@twitterFeed"}
        {{/data}}
              <li>{{text}}</li>
     {{/datasource}}
     </ul>
  </body>
  </html>
```

This code produces the following output in my email:

> ### Feed
>
> - RT @marketingcloud: Just the Facts: 5 Pearls of Marketing Wisdom Based on Data https://t.co/88vBilrLeW https://t.co/07b7B7nr8D
> - RT @ABCNews24: The website for the minister responsible for the census is "down for maintenance" #Census2016 #auspol https://t.co/sQ0VQlpQnG
> - What happens when every household in Australia logs in to the same website on the same evening. #censusfail https://t.co/ydLlmoJq9f
> - RT @sfmcdg: Hope to see you at integrating third party events into #Salesforce #MarketingCloud #JourneyBuilder #meetup https://t.co/DhW1WxJ…
> - Tragic news https://t.co/WnBtM5r7Ls :-( @kellyjandrews

Similarly, you can use Facebook's [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) to achieve the same for Facebook posts and comments.

### Caution

While dynamically retrieving social media feeds at send time will work, I'd really only recommend it for a low triggered send volumes. If you are planning to use this approach to blast a list of 10,000 subscribers then there are a couple of problems:

1. It's **extremely inefficient** to retrieve the same response 10,000 times.
2. More importantly, most API's have some sort of **rate limiting** which restrict the number of API requests you can make in a given timeframe. For example, for the Twitter's user_timeline that I used above has a [rate limit](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits) of 300 requests every 15 mins.

If you need to include the same social media feed in an email to many subscribers, you would be better to use SSJS in a Script Activity (which is triggered by a Scheduled Automation) and store the JSON object in a Data Extension. Then in your email, use AMPscript to lookup the DE field and GTL to display it.

Comment: The Script Activity in an Automation is our go-to method for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can use the [**HTTPGet()**](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/http/HTTPGet.html) function inside an email, **BUT** only if you have a reliable, *public* (does not require authentication) web service that will output Facebook or Twitter JSON or XML.